Rviz namespace, Allow nonzero velocity error / ros2_control_manager
I made package of my 7axis robot arm.
https://github.com/chanhuirobot/rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm
I have two warning message, but it does not make any problem of my robot.
But I want to know what are there problems, and how to solve these.
Can you help me..?


chanhuirobot@chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV:~$ ros2 launch rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_moveit_config bringup.launch.py ros2_control_plugin:=fake
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/chanhuirobot/.ros/log/2024-08-27-17-43-45-769294-chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV-6993
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [6999]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [7001]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [7003]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [7005]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [7007]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [7009]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [7011]
[rviz2-4] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_left
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_right
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link5
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Initialize hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotarmSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotarmSystem'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loaded robot model in 0.00134251 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loading robot model 'rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm'...
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'hand_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [WARN]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Loaded hand_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'hand_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position].
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Configured and activated hand_controller
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Loading controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [WARN]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Loaded arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Configuring controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position].
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Configured and activated arm_controller
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7007]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7011]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 7009]
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-3] [WARN]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-3] [ERROR]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for hand_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Trajectory execution is not managing controllers
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-3] [INFO]: 
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-3] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-3] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-3] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-3] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-3] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-3] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-3] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-3] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[rviz2-4] [ERROR]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Loaded robot model in 0.00194884 seconds
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Loading robot model 'rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm'...
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Service response received for initialization


Set allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: false of both controllers in your  ros2_controllers.yaml file. (You have done nothing wrong, the default value is true, but this changed with newer distros).
The second one is reported here, please ask there for updates.

wow it works! thanks for your help.
